# How to read CSV File dwnloaded from NSE

Tags: python-3.x, csv, request

My Code:

```
import csv
import requests

url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.csv'
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.iter_lines()
reader = csv.reader(text, delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

I am getting the following error:

> _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: don't tag questions with unrelated tags (i.e. selenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the csv separately and then read in with pandas:

```
import pandas
pd.read_csv('SO/AN_LATEST_ANNOUNCED.csv')
```

Result:

[image]

(To save the file separately just open the link in a browser.)

Comment: For me it works. Are you aware if you are doing anything differently than me?

Comment: I am using PyCharm. urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: If you do it with wget, then yes. But if you just save it from a normal Google Chrome?

Comment: Dont use pycharm, use any browser to save the file.

Comment: I will be helpful with anyway to read it to dataframe using PyCharm..?